# Is there a particular term for this eyesight problem?

Tags: eye, computers, vision, scintilla-flashing-lights, scotomas-blind-spots

I have had for the past few months, and today I spend a couple hours trying to identify it and have had no luck.

Certain areas of my vision will change to be "darker" -  but it seems as it those areas are just only partially registered in my brain rather than darker, like a mix between a blind spot and an area with normal vision. The areas never form at the center of my field of view, but form off to the side, tending to manifest as large regions that extend from a curved edge off to the edge of my field of view. The symptom seems most present when viewing a laptop display, and does not vary in severity based on the brightness of the screen.

It seems vaguely related to scotoma - what I am seeing is similar to a less severe, more static and more dispersed version of the "depiction of a scintillating scotoma" animation in [the scotoma wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotoma).

Relative information

1. Age: 15
2. Vision: near-sighted
3. I use a laptop frequently, so that may be related to the issue.